# Использование кода в нескольких проектах VisualStudio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

Например, несколько проектов в одном решении используют функции объявленные в `Functions.h` и реализованные в `Functions.cpp`, а также некоторые абстракции из `Structs.h` с реализацией методов в `Structs.cpp`. 
Иметь эти файлы для каждого проекта не удобно: внес изменения в один - надо внести во все остальные. Хочется иметь отдельную папку, например, `SharedSourse` для таких файлов.

В общем, как правильно слинковать эти файлы? Использую `precompiled header`.

Попытка сделать "в лоб"(завести папку, закинуть туда файлы с кодом и переписать пути для `#include` в самом проекте) не прокатила - выдает ошибки линковщика 2001.

И было б еще здорово `precompiled header` тоже запаковать в папку `SharedSourse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается через добавление в каждый проект соответствующего cpp-файла, который лежит в вашем каталоге SharedSourse и добавлением `#include "path\\to\\SharedSourse"` где нужно. Инфа 146%

Comment: А как быть с `precompiled header`?

Comment: @Dmitry не знаю, исторически сложилось что не использую.